# Switch the Odd One Out

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

[image]

What two figures - one in range a-i and the other in range 1-9 - is the odd ones that should be switched to restore both patterns, and why?

*created by myself*

Comment: It is easy to 'guess' the right answer. But this puzzle is so complicated, nice design!

Comment: Thanks, I am working on a new one where I try to eliminate the possibility to easy guess the solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Well, this answer is probably quite non-creative (I blame the late hour) but here goes... by just counting the symbols we can group them (see colors). Some quirks... the black square (in red group) disappeared, so I guess it is behind the white square. Same applies to the black arrow. Objects may change color, but not shape using the given categorization. (Also, probably too obvious to point out: the circles are fixed, which supports the claim below).

This gives

> [image]

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 6):

> This is the same answer as Carl, but with a different process used. I believe the answer is to switch the bottom right box of figure a-i and the middle right box of figure 1-9. This is because when you draw black vertical lines like the one in the picture I attached you have the same numbers of squares and they are in the same orientation, but with different symbols(except for the middle square in the 1-9 figure). The only line of boxes that does not match up is the one that goes from the middle left box, to the bottom middle box in figure 1-9. To make this the same trough all of the boxes I would switch the boxes marked with the red lines. [image]

Comment: Nice spotted about the squares, I did mark Carls answer as the solution because he answered an hour earlier, but your answer is equally correct